# Laws of logic to simplify expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Trying to understand how to simplify more complex formula's, for example

$ \lnot ([(\lnot \lor ) \land (\lnot \land  \land )] \lor \lnot)$

I've started with this:

$=   ¬ [(¬ ∨ ) ∧ (¬ ∧  ∧ )] ∧ ¬¬ $ (de Morgans Law)

$=   ¬ [(¬ ∨ ) ∧ (¬ ∧  ∧ )] ∧  $ (double negation)

$=  (¬ (¬ ∨ ) ∨ ¬ (¬ ∧  ∧ )) ∧ $ (de Morgans law)

$=  ((¬¬ ∧ ¬) ∨  (¬¬ ∨ ¬ ∨ ¬)) ∧  $ (de Morgans law)

$= (( ∧ ¬) ∨ ( ∨ ¬ ∨ ¬)) ∧ $  (double negation)

$= (( ∧ ¬) ∧ ) ∨ (( ∨ ¬ ∨ ¬) ∧  )$ (Distributive)

$= (( ∧ ¬) ∧ ) ∨ ( ∧ ) ∨ (¬ ∧  ) ∨ (¬ ∧  ) $  (Distributive)

However I think I'm going down the wrong track and would appreciate some help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might become easier to manipulate such logical expression, if you use another way of writing it as shown below. Then, logical manipulations become mere algebraic manipulation:

- $P\lor Q= P+Q$, $P\land Q = P\cdot Q = PQ$, $\lnot P = \overline{P}$, $0 =F$, $1=T$
- Then De-Morgan reads as follows: $ \overline{P+Q} = PQ$
- Distributivity of $\land$: $(P+Q)R = PR+QR$
- Tautology and contradiction etc.: $Q\overline Q = 0$, $Q + \overline Q = 1$, $1+Q = 1$, etc.

That way, the transformation of your expression becomes quite short and easy to read:

$$ \overline{  (\overline{Q} + R)(\overline{P} Q R)  + \overline{R}   } \stackrel{de Morgan}{=} \overline{  (\overline{Q} + R)(\overline{P} Q R) }R  \stackrel{Distr.\;\&\; Q\bar Q=0}{=} \overline{ (  \overline{P} Q R) }   R  \stackrel{de Morgan}{=} (P + \overline{Q} + \overline{R})R \stackrel{Distr.\;\&\; R\bar R=0}{=}  (P + \overline{Q})R$$

Comment: Would you mind explaining the 2nd step again? The one with the distributive law? I understand the basis of it from what I've been taught, but I'm not sure what you're doing it with apart from the (q'+r)? I definitely agree that it's easier to do it as the shorthand notation, I should've done that sooner

Comment: In the second step I do the following (note that $AB = BA$): $ (\overline{Q} + R)(\overline{P} Q R)  \stackrel{Distr.}{=}  \overline{Q}\, \overline{P} Q R + R \overline{P} Q R \stackrel{Q\bar Q=0 \;\&\; RR=R}{=} 0\cdot \overline{P} R + \overline{P} Q R  \stackrel{0+X = X}{=}\overline{P} Q R$

Comment: Now that's clicked, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

> $=(( ∧ ¬) ∧ ) ∨ ( ∧ ) ∨ (¬ ∧  ) ∨ (¬ ∧  ) $  (Distributive)
>
> However I think I'm going down the wrong track and would appreciate some help.

No, that's okay.  Follow with :

$=(( ∧ ¬) ∧ ) ∨ ( ∧ ) ∨ (¬ ∧  ) ∨ 0 $  (Complementation)

$=(( ∧ ¬) ∧ ) ∨ ( ∧ ) ∨ (¬ ∧  )$  (Identity)

And similarly simplify the rest.

> (Hint: next is Association)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips:

Do you see how the term $\neg q \lor r$ is being conjuncted with $(\neg p \land q \land r)$?

Well, since that last term is a conjunction itself, you can drop the parentheses around them. So:

$(\neg q \lor r) \land (\neg p \land q \land r)=(\neg q \lor r) \land \neg p \land q \land r$

Now, the $r$ term will absorb the $\neg q \lor r$ term, and so:

$(\neg q \lor r) \land \neg p \land q \land r = \neg p \land q \land r$

Now, that term gets disjuncted with $\neg r$. Here is a handy equivalence:

**Reduction**

$\neg p \land (p \lor q) = \neg p \land q$

$\neg p \lor (p \land q) = \neg p \lor q$

So, using Reduction:

$[\neg p \land q \land r] \lor \neg r = [\neg p \land q] \lor \neg r$

OK, so now negate that, do a few DeMorgan's and you are done.

In general: Absorption and Reduction are your real friends when it comes to simplifying. Distribution on the other hand can make things more difficult ... unless your u go the other way around (i.e. 'undistribute')

Comment: That way was a lot simpler than I was doing. We've always been told to do the deMorgans part first but that seemed to make it a lot harder to follow